# How can I hook up player input to an action in RPGMaker?

Tags: input, rpg-maker-vx

How do I set a player input to perform an animation such as swinging a sword.

I tried doing it by creating a parallel process in which hitting `z` calls the following common event.

```
Change Party Member: Add [mage sheild], Initialize
Change Party Member: Remove [Mage]
```

Effectively making the animation a party member that can be switched to. This doesn't really work at all. I tried looking at Sapphire ABS to see how they do it, but I can't find a definition for `$Game_player` in the code. So I'm sorta incredibly lost.

Comment: When you say "That doesn't really work at all" what do you mean? What happens?

Comment: Nothing happens when the command key is input. So the process is meant to check if the player has hit z and change a party member. Yet hitting z yeilds no result.